# Can I pass a whole string as one command line argument into argv in C?

Tags: c, argv

Say I have a program like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("The name of the program is %s, and the string passed is:\n %s \n\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I realize there should be error checking and whatnot, but what I'd really like to know is how to pass a whole string as the first argument or if it's even possible. Thanks!

Comment: If you compile this program (as `a.out`) and run `a.out coffeeNcode`, you'll get the name of the program as `a.out` and the string passed as `coffeeNcode`. What's the problem?

Comment: This is shell-dependent, but generally if you put single quotes around a command-line argument, it's treated as a single string rather than broken by spaces. EX: ``./exe This Is A String`` will be broken into ``"This" "Is" "A" "String"``, where as ``./exe 'This Is A String`` will just be ``"This Is A String"``

Comment: @aruisdante - are you missing a closing quote? Should be `./exe 'This Is A String'`

Comment: I figured it out, it wasn't the quotes, it was because I had an exclamation point in my string when I tested the code on my machine. I'm on Mac OS and the error that I got was "bash: !": event not found".

Comment: @Benesh whoops, yep. But can't edit now thanks to the 5 minute window :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use quotes

```
./file_name "This is the long string argument that comes in argv[1]"
     |
     |
     +--- argv[0]
```

---

**Edit**:

aruisdante: [*single and double quotes are treated depending on the shell, double quotes might do unexpected things*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458204/can-i-pass-a-whole-string-as-one-command-line-argument-into-argv-in-c/23458255?noredirect=1#comment35961107_23458255)

<sup>*PS: My answer comes from Windows platform, where use of single quote, simply skips everything after whitespace*</sup>

Comment: There is a difference in how single and double quotes are treated depending on the shell ([example](http://askubuntu.com/questions/432525/when-to-use-single-or-double-quotes-in-ubuntu-command-line)). They'll both work, but double quotes might do unexpected things.

Comment: So it's best to stick with single quotes in most cases?

Comment: @coffeeNcode If you want a raw string to be passed, yes. Double quotes allow for shell expansions, like history replacement with bangs.

Comment: @aruisdante Ouhh I'm not aware of any such unexpected thing

Comment: Basically, most shells treat ``'...'`` as a raw string (I.E. no special characters are expanded), and ``"..."`` as a formatted string where all special characters are evaluated. So, for example, if you want to pass the *value* of an environment variable you'd use ``"$VAR"``, but if you wanted to pass the actual var-name such that it could be used internally, you'd use ``'$VAR'``. Likewise ``\`` is treated as an escape character in ``"\"`` but not in ``'\'``.

Comment: @aruisdante Okay, But I'm on windows, If I use single quotes it simple skips everything after whitespace

Comment: @P0W That's why I said it was *shell dependent* ;)

Comment: @aruisdante Excellent! The reason I ran into problems was because I used double quotes and had an exclamation point at the end of the string, but when I used single quotes didn't have any problems. So it must've been trying to evaluate the '!'