# Is there any way to accept all the parameters as a single string?

Tags: c, dos, c89, turbo-c

For example,

Input:

```
echo( hello world
```

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int n,char** args){
// Replace all the '\0' with ' '
system(args[1]);
return printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
hello world
```

Now I need hello world in a pointer.

I know that `**char` doesn't work the way I want it to..

But is there any efficient way out, instead of calculating the length of each argument, malloc-ing those many bytes and then concatenating it to the allocated memory?

Some access specifier for `char**` maybe?

**I am trying to add `echo(` a command to DOSBox, so basically `echo params` and then print a newline. That's it.**

Also, is there any way to exclude to recognize an exe without any spaces or is it console specific?

Comment: Why not just `myexe "hello world"` ?

Comment: you can't influence it in `myexe` but you can call `myexe "hello word"` then the whole string is in `argv[1]`

Comment: I am trying to add `echo(` to my DOSBox...But thanks alot, that helped me to solve another problem.

Comment: We can accept those arguments using argc and argv. Then we can use those accordingly.

Comment: @VikasVijayan True that, but that's a lot of work for the computer. I mean we won't feel it, but I was looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I pass a whole string as one command line argument into argv in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458204/can-i-pass-a-whole-string-as-one-command-line-argument-into-argv-in-c)

Comment: SanderDeDycker and Ingo Leonhardt have given the same solution. Unfortunately, no.

Comment: You are using vague terms to describe what you want.  _More efficient_ is not a specific specification.  If you really want help with a problem, describe what the problem is in terms, and by the way using a [mcve] to illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want a way to get all the arguments in a single pointer, a string that's terminated at the end.

Comment: And people have already offered the answer.  Surround whatever content you want by double quotes in the command line of your executable `"this,is,a,beautiful,day"` could be easily parsed from being a single string contained in a single variable `argv[1]`.

Comment: I am trying to simulate the echo( command on my DOSBox.

Comment: _I am trying to simulate the echo( command on my DOSBox_: please [edit] your question and elaborate.

Comment: @HelloWorld : please try the proposed solution first before you say it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: `echo( Hello World` --> system(argsfrom1) + printf("\n")

Comment: The ironic part is that it is the MS-DOS program's C startup code that is responsible for parsing the command line and constructing the `argv` array before `main` is called. So you want access to that "lower level" version of the command line. Windows has a `GetCommandLine` function to do that, but I don't know what the equivalent is in Turbo C's DOS libraries.

Comment: With "simulate the `echo(` command" you mean "echo an empty line"? In DOS you can use `echo/` instead.

Comment: Ok wait..That could have been the correct answer. Please post it. Thank you.

Comment: @Hello: done. That is an extreme example of an XY-Problem `:D`

Comment:  Lol, you still remember Sir @MichaelPetch' s words

Comment: @IanAbbott: In tiny model, the argument string is placed at CS:0x0080 to CS:0x00FF before a program starts.  I don't know if Turbo C leaves it there, or if it overwrites it.  I think there's a way to ask for the program startup prefix segment in other memory models, but I don't remember what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo an empty line, in Windows `cmd`, the best method is `echo(`, but also common are `echo/`, `echo.` and some more variations.

The (best for `cmd`) `echo(` doesn't work in DOS (results in a `bad command or filename` error), but `echo/` works fine even in DOS.

Answer (score 1):

*I want a way to get all the arguments in a single pointer, a string that's terminated at the end.*

Using either form of the `main()` function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {...};
int main(int argc, char **argv) {...};
```

which are equivalent signatures for the `C main()` function, will allow you to pass any number of arguments, each of any size.  If you want to pass a single string containing many arguments just pass a single string with some kind of delimiter.  If the delimiter is a space ( `" "` ), then by definition of the [behavior of the `C main()` function command line argument](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm) requires surrounding them with `"`:

Say your exe name is prog.exe

```
prog this,is,one,argument
prog "this is one argument"  //double quotes provide cohesion between space delimited command line arguments 
prog this-is-one-argument
```

Will all be contained in a single variable:  `argv[1]`

If you compile this as `echo.exe` it will put to `stdout` any thing typed into `stdin`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if(argv != 2) return 0;
  fputs(argv[1], stdout);
  return(0);
}
```

Usage: `echo "this will be echoed onto stdout"<return>`
Usage: `abc000<return>`
Usage: `this-is-one-argument<return>`

Comment: @HelloWorld -  `argv[1]` is provided as pointer to a single string, i.e. specifically to the first argument of your call to `prog.exe`

Comment: Yeah and it writes 0 to all the other memory location so that it actually looks like an indexable 2D array.

Comment: @HelloWorld - have you looked at the link I provided describing how command line processing is defined for the `C` `main(...)` function?  If `argc == 2`, then by definition there will only be 2 elements to `*argv[]`:  `argv[0]` and `argv[1]`

Comment: Yes actually this method helped me to solve another problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make it one line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char oneline[256] = "";
    for(int index = 1; index < argc; index++) 
    {
        strcat(oneline, argv[index]);
        strcat(oneline, " ");
    }

    printf("parameters: "%s"\n", oneline);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/B4ULLB

This is only the idea and it can be done much more efficiently - for example by not using strcat or more efficiently allocate the memory. But the idea will be the same. You can also do not add the last space (it is for nitpickers)

Comment: Can `echo(` be replicated in DOS without spaces?